# Whoops! Low disk space!

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I wasn't expecting to use Ubuntu for so long, and I heard that the partition thingy is fixed, you only get to pick how much space you want **once**

You can't go back, that's what I heard

Is there a way to increase the partition size 'without' blowing up the drive? Last time I used Gparted it emptied my drive that held my windows installation and files

Since my Bitcoin wallet is stored on the windows partition, I'm not touching gparted this time

Answer (score 0):

With a dual-boot system, any partition changes can be dangerous.  Make a clonezilla (or similar program) backup of your entire drive before making any changes to your system.  This way, if you muck it up, you can always restore the image and try again.  I cannot stress this enough.  Make a good backup first!

If you boot into windows (Vista or newer), you can use the drive management system to shrink your windows partition.  (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Disk Mangement) Right click on your windows partition, and click Shrink Volume.  Then, re-boot into Ubuntu and use Gparted to increase the size of the Ubuntu partition to take up the newly freed space.

Gparted is your best bet for resizing your linux partition.  Windows is your best bet for resizing your windows partition.

If done in that order, you should be good to go!

Comment: If you do not get much space freed up with the Windows "Shrink Volume" ability, defrag the partition and try again.  There are several pages dedicated to helping people get as much space as possible from this tool, so do a search if the defrag does not work.